# QR CODE max char length

Tags: qr-code

I've read that QRCODES has about 4,290 alphanumeric chars limit (about 4kb).

Is it true and is there any way to increase their memory size?

I would like to have more space on if possible: P

Comment: I found a useful table [here](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/character-capacities) that shows the capacity of each mode taking into account the error correction level used.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

A summary of the specification is here:

```
  * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

    Numeric only    Max. 7,089 characters (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    Alphanumeric    Max. 4,296 characters (0–9, A–Z [upper-case only], space, $, %, *, +, -, ., /, :)
    Binary/byte     Max. 2,953 characters (8-bit bytes) (23624 bits)
    Kanji/Kana  Max. 1,817 characters
```

The specification itself is here:

- https://www.iso.org/standard/62021.html

As far as "more space", you should think of the QR code as a "link", or a "shortcut" to your URL.  Clicking the QR code brings the user to web site; once they're there, you have as much space as you want.

Comment: QR codes are not just for storing URLs. See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51771/where-do-you-store-your-personal-private-gpg-key) on backing up

Comment: The point is, one should think of a QR code as "more like a URL".  One should *NOT* think of QR codes as "like a database".

Comment: @oldmankit is right. The idea that QR's "_should_" be thought of as paulsm4 describes misses the **entire wealth of possible uses** for QR codes other than just quick URL shortcuts. See http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/howtouse.html for some applications other than URL's. An excellent use of QR codes as a "database" is on MedicAlert type jewelry. While the tags have human readable summaries (ex: ALLERGIES, DIABETIC), a version 8-M code (49x49) can hold 221 alphanumeric characters to give details of these conditions *IN TEXT* to the first-responder. URL's are worthless if you have no internet.

Comment: Thanks, @O.M.Y. While paulsm4's answer is definitely helpful, I think the whole "you should think" paragraph could be taken out to make the answer even better. I don't see any compelling evidence for why I should think that way!

Comment: How about batching a pile of QR images into one blob? Some sort of a punched tape ;)

Comment: @DaneelYaitskov there seems to be a standard for that now. https://hub.packtpub.com/introducing-txqr-data-transfer-via-animated-qr-codes/

Answer (score 8):

QR codes come in various standardized sizes, but the largest is version 40
which can store about 2,953 bytes. 2953 character is the maximum that you can store within a single QR code

Mattkc has a video on youtube, where he stores the snake game within a QR code. It's quite awesome check it out.

```
https://mattkc.com/etc/snakeqr/
```

[image]