# Using Multiple Input to Generate QR code

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using this code for QR code generator from one input field:(HTML and Javascript)
I want to have multiple input, like guest name, and event title, event date, location to be as one part to form or generate QR code. 
Note that event title and date is going to be filled one time, while guest name is going to be multiple, as the goal is to have unique QR code per each guest.

So the final result should be event title, date and location as well as QR code are going to be embedded as 1 photo. 
Is that possible?

Thanks
-Tarneem

```js
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode");

function makeCode () {      
    var elText = document.getElementById("text");
    
    if (!elText.value) {
        elText.focus();
        return;
    }
    
    qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
}

makeCode();

$("#text").
    on("blur", function () {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });
```

```html
                  <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter guest name"  class="contactField" /><br />
 <div id="qrcode" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's very easy actually, just concat them:

```
var location = 'exampleLocation';
// Some other information or methods how you get the info here 

var qrCodeString = location+ ', ' +$('#name').val();
qrcode.makeCode(elText.value( qrCodeString );
```

Your code doesn't show where you get the location and event info from, but you can just add them to the QR generator. [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764334/qr-code-max-char-length) you can have about 4.000 characers in as max length of the string.

Comment: actually the info is going to be input, means the user will type it. I tried your code but once I combine it with the QRcode script, the QR code figure disappear

Comment: If you can get me, I need to do this one in the video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LMjceCl1k8

Answer (score 0):

Use qrcode libary https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode

```
var QRCode = require('qrcode')

let qrcod_url = await QRCode.toDataURL([
{ data: 'Confidential \n', mode: 'byte' },
{ data: `Date: ${moment(created_at).format('MM-DD-YYYY')}\n`, mode: 'byte'},
{ data: `Gender : ${customerGender}\n`, mode: 'byte' },
])
```